# Looking for a high speed, high powered motor

Tags: dc-motor, high-speed

So I'm trying something that has been attempted before and that is to have an electric turbo charger.

essentially the goal is to spin a compressor wheel (20 grams) at 150k RPMS and sustain it for about 3 - 4 seconds. I've been told I need the power output to be at least 5kw in order to achieve this.

I have the battery system figured out and I'm at the point where I need to find this unicorn of sorts!

Is this even possible? I know Volvo and Audi have electric turbo chargers so there most be something out there right?

Thanks for the help! I'm a bit new to motors in general so explanations would be incredibly welcomed!

Comment: Are you trying to make an electric-assist turbocharger or an electrically driven supercharger?

Comment: Originally I wanted an electrically driven supercharger but I'm open to suggestions about an assist type set up

Comment: The mass of the compressor wheel is irrelevant. What matters is the amount of air you want to move and the amount of pressure boost you're trying to achieve. Have you considered experimenting with the motors and impellers from large shop vacuum cleaners? They're generally "universal" type motors and will run fine on DC if you boost the voltage up high enough.

Comment: Brushless DC. (Or Joel's synchronous AC, which are essentially the same) Look at electric R/C flight, you'll find speeds and power levels within an order of magnitude of what you need - maybe 1-2kw and over 50,000 rpm a few years ago. They call this a "ducted fan".

Comment: A ducted fan possibly might work! Let me do some research to find some ducted fan motors.. this may be the answer to my problem!

Comment: Does anyone know how to convert Kv to rpms? I'm a bit new to this and can't figure out what's the maximum volts the following Item can take:

http://www.hobbypartz.com/77p-lbp2860-b-2d-5050kv.html

is it 11v?

Comment: In 1956 Studebaker "Golden Hawk" had a mechanical supercharger mounted on their engine, with an electric clutch like A/C's have, that would engage when energized by a button switch mounted under the fuel peddle. The smaller engine could provide reasonable fuel mileage and yet have plenty of passing power.

Comment: A link to an article re:Supercharger use long ago in many models http://vs57.y-block.info/road_test.htm

Answer (score 1):

First off: Why? If this is being used in a vehicle, then you are converting kinetic energy to electric in the alternator, then back to kinetic in a motor.

The point of this is for dynamic response? A mechanical supercharger is still probably better here (but i understand its a lot less fun to build...) Another solution is a normal turbocharger with some mildly clever (fun!) electronics to control a simple anti-lag system. I have some ideas for this...

I have seen electric superchargers before and found them a little ridiculous from an engineering standpoint, due to the immense power consumption normally derived from a 12V source. 5kW does sound reasonable for a small-ish capacity engine with fairly low boost pressure.

The ones I have seen use a small synchronous AC motor, which can easily be driven with a high frequency (2500Hz for 4 poles and 150krpm). Bowever, as you said, this is a bit of a unicorn.

A simpler solution might be to use a starter motor (at least available) and a high-ratio belt drive. The link below use a clever system like this to run a centrifugal blower from the crankshaft

http://www.brennanracing.com/supercharger.html

Also, worth knowing that the centrifugal type compressor will have an exponential response. Double the speed, four times the airflow. Bit of a pain to control. The other option is a screw-type supercharger (look up Opcon Autorotor AB). Bang a starter motor in that and you might be laughing. (Or attach it to the crank like a normal person...)

Comment: I guess the advantage of using the battery is that you don't suck power from the motor right when you need it, assuming you only want a burst of power. There might be other ways (a flywheel?)

Comment: Another better way is to use a normal exhaust-driven turbocharger! A flywheel might be fun to build, but a little dangerous. A properly designed system doesnt really have much turbo lag

Comment: @Joel The thing with track cars is that you either build for power to be later in the power band or sooner. If I were to stick a GT35R turbo then I'd have to wait much later in my revs (around 4k rpm) in order to reach full boost. This is assuming the engine displacement is 2.5L. My goal is to fill in the lack of power between 1k-4k.

For the record, I already have a normal exhaust driven turbocharge (a 20g to be exact). I'm pondering the possibility of adding a second one to assist in the low end of the powerband.

Answer (score 0):

Celertron has just come out with [a new range of motors that spin up to 500,000 RPM](http://www.celeroton.com/en/products/motors.html) using magnetic bearings.

Comment: This looks promising but it's rated at 100w power output.. I'd have to install 50 of these in order to maintain proper boost levels (7 -10 psi)